# Do I require Spring Cloud Kubernetes for Spring boot cloud native application?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am working on a Spring boot based cloud native application to be deployed on Kubernetes cluster. As Spring offers Spring Cloud Kubernetes for integration with Kubernetes deployments, do I really need to use it for cloud native app ?

Spring doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#why-do-you-need-spring-cloud-kubernetes) not much convincing whether to use it or not?
If I use it, whether will it give me significant benefits in developing 12 factor apps ?

I think most of cloud native app behaviors are enforced by Kubernetes itself.

Please let me know if I am missing anything in seeing the value for Spring cloud Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't.  If Spring Cloud doesn't offer some particular benefit you want or need in interacting with Kubernetes, then there's no reason to use it.  Pretty much any container you have available will run fine in Kubernetes.  Nothing about the configuration of the container has to know or care if it might be running in Kubernetes.  So, certainly, your app doesn't have to know.